# Call Web Service on Submit in NetSuite

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'm trying to call a web service using jquery on a user event script in NetSuite, but I am having a lot of trouble. Whenever I use my call, the debugger throws this error:

```
org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "jQuery" is not defined. (testscript.js$1564$debugger.user#22)
```

At first I figured I just needed to add jQuery to the page, but I know NetSuite normally includes JQuery on every page.

Am I going about this the correct way? How does one go about calling a web service in NetSuite using SuiteScript 2.0?

Comment: If you open your console while on the page and type just "jQuery" and hit enter, what does the console print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Suitescript 2.0 use N/https or N.http module for call webservice.

try below code for get webservice call

```
var response = https.request({
    method: https.Method.GET,
    url: 'https://www.testwebsite.com'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

var Response = https.get({
                url: Ours'URL,
                headers: headers
            });